# Difficulies switching career from Java to Python; how can I land offers for this new role?

Tags: software-industry, career-switch

I have few years of experience as a senior java team leader, but now I have finished my master's degree in AI and I would like to work in this field (with python). I have no commercial experience in python but I feel comfortable with it and most of the popular libraries. The problem is 100% of the offers that I am receiving are related to java. I have lowered my salary expectations with AI to 1/3 of what they offer me in java but still, no offers in AI.

Another problem is that in the current company I am also an IT manager, but I have no problem becoming junior python/AI/data science dev again. I feel like it scares recruiters away (since month when I have added "manager" to LinkedIn, I am getting like 5x less offers).

I feel like recruiters think *"oh, he can get 3x cash in java than in python so I'll just offer him java because surely everyone lives only for money"*.

It's like my past experience is working against me instead of helping me, which is quite surprising to me. The only way I see is removing from cv my java and managing experience and play the role of a wannabe junior python without commercial experience, but this seems quite cheesy especially if they will ask directly.

What can I do to get a job and change my specialization from senior java to junior python?

Comment: Are you actively applying to python AI positions? If so, are you able to make it to the interview phase?

Answer (score 3):

> The only way I see is removing from cv my java and managing experience and play the role of a wannabe junior python without commercial experience, but this seems quite cheesy especially if they will ask directly.

Given this phrase we can conclude that you are including your java and manager information on your CV while applying for Python jobs.

This is perhaps what is harming you here, as **one should tailor your CV for the role one is applying**, and include only the relevant and on-topic skills, perks, etc., you have for that role.

So, I suggest you **tailor your CV and include the experience and knowledge relevant for a Python position**. Try to not include your Java or manager knowledge (or try to favor including Python facts first), as it is unrelated to the job you seek. This is not "cheesy" at all.

Eventually, if they ask you about other experience you've had or if they ask you directly about Java then you can proceed to tell them about such, no need to deny it. Also, it's unlikely they say *"why didn't you include your Java experience on your CV"*, because that is not what they are looking for in this Python offer, so don't worry about that.

Comment: Slight disagreement - the OP should include total programming experience, without necessarily specifying languages. A competent Java programmer is likely to become a competent Python programmer quicker than someone who is starting from scratch.

Comment: It would be good if you post your alternative POV in an answer, so everyone can consider it and benefit from it. Personally, I would avoid mentioning non-relevant experience, as it will only take place that one could use for relevant info, bring noise to the CV and reduce it's impact... If there is space left I would consider mentioning other experience, or include it in some sort of "other programming experience"... still, when/if OP mentions past jobs there they could briefly mention such roles and experience with java etc. Editing my wording in the answer

Answer (score 2):

> I have lowered my salary expectations with AI to 1/3 of what they
>   offer me in java but still, no offers in AI.

This is your true problem: you want a job in AI, but they don't want to offer you a job in AI.

Python or Java is just a tool, and it is irrelevant here. Often in the coding interviews, you are free to choose whatever language you are comfortable with.

I have also never heard about a position such as *software engineer in Java* or *swe in Python*. A swe needs to use/learn whatever language the project requires. And even if Java is your main language, you will need Python anyway, e.g. for scripting.

Back to your problem, if you want to get a job in AI, then you need to improve your background and experience in AI: do some projects on github, join Kaggle competitions etc etc.

Answer (score 1):

You don't switch from being senior to junior just because you learn a new language. Being an experience developer has very little to do with what language you use.

Here are some things I would do:

- Look for a job that will accept you without Python experience. This is probably the most difficult. But if you are a good developer this shouldn't be impossible.
- Apply for jobs that are looking for people with both Java and Python experience. This is a good way to get professional experience while gradually learning a new language.
- Write a bunch of Python programs, games or apps and put it on your Github.
- Join a Python open source project and contribute a lot.

Answer (score 0):

One issue that may be holding you back is switching both language and problem domain at the same time. It may be better to begin by looking for AI jobs using Java, or Python jobs in your current area, and only make the other switch later.

I would list total programming experience on the resume, without specifying the language, because an experienced programmer will get up to speed on Python faster than someone without programming experience.